# Basic Search Function for cakePHP 2.0 App - Notice (8): Undefined index: search error

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I am a newB with cakePHP and I am enjoying it but fnding that there is a stiff learning curve...

Anyway I am trying to get a basic search set up in view that searches only one table for it results. This is for a cakePHP 2.0 app. I am getting the dreaded Notice (8): Undefined index: search error.

Everything else works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my CustomersController  code

```
/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->layout = 'front';
        //  $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'Customer' => array(
                'paramType' => 'querystring',
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array('Customer.created' => 'desc'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->Customer->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('customers', $this->Paginator->paginate());


/**
 *  Search Method
 *
 *
 */ 
    public function search() {
      if ($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post')) {
        // poor man's Post Redirect Get behavior
        return $this->redirect(array(
          '?' => array(
            'q' => $this->request->data('Customer.searchQuery')
          )
        ));
      }
      $this->Customer->recursive = 0;
      $searchQuery = $this->request->query('q');
      $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Customer' => array(
          'findType' => 'search',
          'searchQuery' => $searchQuery
        )
      );
      $this->set('customers', $this->Paginator->paginate());
      $this->set('searchQuery', $searchQuery);
      $this->render('index');
    }
```

Here is my Customer Model

```
/**
 * customer Model
 *
 */
class customer extends AppModel {

    public $findMethods = array('search' => true);

    protected function _findSearch($state, $query, $results = array()) {
      if ($state === 'before') {
        $searchQuery = Hash::get($query, 'searchQuery');
        $searchConditions = array(
          'or' => array(
            "{$this->alias}.name LIKE" => '%' . $searchQuery . '%',
            "{$this->alias}.interest LIKE" => '%' . $searchQuery . '%'
          )
        );
        $query['conditions'] = array_merge($searchConditions, (array)$query['conditions']);
        return $query;
      }
      return $results;
    }
```

Again any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are getting error `Notice (8): Undefined index:` But Where you get this notice ??? 1) On which Line ? 2) In controller or model ??? 3)Edit the Question and add Line where you get message .4) What query you are getting at the bottom ?

Comment: I get the error in the resulting view. Now here is the kicker. This only happens on a live site. I loaded this up in my laptop and XAMPP and it works perfectly.... Now I am really stumped.

Comment: I am wondering if I am having an issue with the core on the live version.

Comment: Check if all files are same on server like on Local ? Then Goto core.php , set debug mode to 0 and then to 2 , Hope it will work

Comment: Yes all files are identical. I downloaded from live site to my laptop then ran it on XAMPP and everything worked fine. I also setn debug to 0 which only removed the SQL at the bottom of the page. Thanks. The only diference between the two environments that I can find is the version of PHP. On the live server 5.3.21 and in XAMPP i am running 5.5...

Comment: switch core to 2 again .

Comment: Switching core debug back to 2 just brings back the Notice (8): Undefined Index: search error again.

Comment: I am going to upgrade the hosting account to PHP 5.5 and see if that fixes the problem. I will keep you posted.

Comment: So... I was able to get some expert help on this situation from Jorge at cakePHP and he pointed out that the Model is where my problems lie. I have a lower case Model name of: customer and a lower case custom finder of _findsearch.. Should be Customer and _findSearch  I Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Oh god , its common Cakephp Or any Object oriented PHP to have 1st letter of class as Capital.